# Reproduzir áudio em javascript automaticamente

Tags: javascript, áudio

Tenho este script, que quando eu clico ele reproduz o audio:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<div id="oi" onclick="reproduzir('audio01.mp3')">ME CLIQUE</div>

<audio id="audio">
    <source src="" type="audio/mpeg">
    Seu navegador não possui suporte ao elemento audio
</audio>

</html>

<script>
    audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    function reproduzir(urlMusica){
        audio.src = urlMusica;
        audio.play();

    }   

</script>
```

e queria que ele reproduzisse sozinho quando uso o "onload" já tentei de várias formas, mas não da certo. alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Não precisa de Js para isto é só setar na tag `audio` a propriedade **autoplay**.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o atributo `autoplay` na sua `tag` audio.

Exemplo:

```
<audio autoplay>
</audio>
```

Mais informações: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_autoplay.asp

Comment: Não deu certo, você testou aí?

Comment: Tentei dessa forma e deu certo, mas sem Js

```
<audio id="audio" autoplay>
    <source src="audio01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Seu navegador não possui suporte ao elemento audio
</audio>
```

Answer (score -1):

O Chrome desabilitou o recurso de autoplay. Para conseguir dar play em alguma midia que possua som, agora é necessário uma interação prévia do usuário, ou pelo menos a página estar marcada como favorita. Segue informação.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Obrigado por esclarecer essa duvida